# Parsing Twitter text (TweetText) with C#

Tags: c#, json, twitter

I use Api1.1 of twitter, I do request:

[https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline)

And in result I have JSon in this format:

```
"created_at":"Thu Mar 14 20:57:55 +0000 2013",
"id":312306622775062528,
"id_str":"312306622775062528",
"text":"RT @AlexPetrukhin: \u0421\u043f\u0435\u0446\u0432\u044b\u043f\u0443\u0441\u043a \u0434\u043d\u0435\u0432\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0430 \u043a\u0438\u043d\u043e\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u044e\u0441\u0435\u0440\u0430: 8 \u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0430: http:\/\/t.co\/vZY3k3GNmZ \u0441 \u043f\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0449\u044c\u044e @youtube \u041b\u0443\u0447\u0448\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u0437\u0434\u043d\u043e, \u0447\u0435\u043c \u043f\u043e\u0442\u043e\u043c... \u0412\u0435\u0441\u043d ...",
"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e",
"truncated":false,
"in_reply_to_status_id":null,
"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
"in_reply_to_user_id":null,
"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
"user":{
..........

"favorited":false,
"retweeted":true,
"possibly_sensitive":false,
"lang":"ru"
```

How parse "**text**" field into HTML?

I found a [library](https://github.com/andyhutch77/oAuthTwitterWrapper/blob/master/WebFormsApplication/js/twitter-text.js) in JS, but I need to parse on servers side in C#

Comment: looks like a regular string containig lots of non-ASCII chars. Guess ist russian... So you could parse it in a string, than add some HTML tags.

Comment: What is the expected output? i.e. what doyou want to see after all processing is done?

Comment: Are you sure you're using a JSON parser in the first place or are you trying to parse it yourself?

Comment: I want to see plain text or html with a href if contains links